# CORS Issue - AWS Elastic Beanstalk and AWS Elastic Cache

Tags: node.js, caching, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I have a Nodejs application deployed on AWS Beanstalk. I have also one AWS Elastic Cache (Redis) deployed which is caching the response of API from AWS Beanstalk.

In simple words, my request to API check whether data is there into the cache or not, IF it is there it is returning the data from cache else returning from database and also saving it inside the cache.

I have multiple origin allowed in CORS configuration in my Nodejs application and my static website built in React is hosted on S3

Now the first time I am sending the request from web app (prod url), request is going through and it is giving me the data. Second time if I am sending the request from my staging web app, it is giving me CORS issue. The error is as:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://api.xxx.com/v1/countries' from origin 'http://xxx-staging.xxx.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://xxx.xxx.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

I have both the domain configured in allowed domain list inside my Nodejs app.

Now if I reboot the Elastic Cache node, and then making the request from Staging web app, it is going through but the next call from prod web app is giving CORS issue.

Do I need to configure something on Elastic Cache to allow multiple origin ? I have a feeling that it is caching the origin, the very first time request is made.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Before downvoting the question, let me know what's the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Try adding a `Vary: Origin` response header to the response

Comment: @sideshowbarker I saw the response header and Vary: Origin is already present in the header.